# lambda and filter in python

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I have the following string and I wanna decode by filtering the X's

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
```

And I would like to filter. I tried the following code

```
message = filter(lambda x: garbled.remove(x) if x == "X", garbled)
```

I did not make this way work. I have found this other solution:

```
message = filter(lambda x: x != "X", garbled)
```

But I still wonder why did not work the first one. Can I fix it?

(I am new in python btw) thanks!

Comment: so you just want to remove all the `'X'`s?

Comment: Strings don't have any `remove` method, because strings are immutable. Your first attempt didn't work because it's trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: why not just `decoded = garbled.replace('X', '')`?

Comment: What happens if there is an `"X"` you want to keep?

Comment: As you're new to Python, you really should be using Python 3 now... all evidecne points out that you're using Python 2...

Comment: also "I did not make this way work" is not a proper bug description!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are right but the explanation was done by Ev.Kounis. I am using an online console and next time I'll also post the error message. thanks for the tips

Comment: @khelwood thanks you are super right this method can not be used there as is list. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter(function, iterable)` does the following procedure:

1. Go through the elements in `iterable` (i.e. the second parameter) one at a time.
2. For each one of those elements, call `function` (i.e. the second parameter) on that element and see whether it returns true.
3. Collect together only those elements where the `function` returned true, and return a new list of those.

Look at what happens in step 2 if you pass `lambda x: garbled.remove(x) if x == "X"` for the `function` parameter: `filter()` says to itself, "Hmm, if I set `x="I"` then is `garbled.remove(x) if x == "X"` true?". It's like you're shouting an instruction at `filter()` in its second parameter: "hey, please remove all the `"X"`s". But that's just not the right thing to go there. The requirements are very precise: it must be a function that takes an element and returns a true or false value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generator expression instead of `filter`

```
>>> ''.join(i for i in garbled if i != 'X')
'I am another secret message!'
```

If you wanted to use `filter` you'd have to change your `lambda` to

```
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled))
'I am another secret message!'
```

Comment: FYI, `join`s are more efficient with lists, i.e. `''.join([i for i in garbled if i != 'X'])` but I can't find the post right now.

Comment: @timgeb True, but most of the time the difference is too small to notice (especially a string as small as in the original question). It's probably not worth the visual clutter unless the performance becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cory already fixed your `filter`.

In my opinion, your problem is handled  best by a simple `str.replace`.

```
>>> garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
>>> garbled.replace('X', '')
'I am another secret message!'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message = filter(lambda x: garbled.remove(x) if x == "X", garbled)
```

This code doesn't work, because lambda function must be expression.

```
garbled.remove(x) if x == "X"
```

This is statement, not a expression.
I delete if x=="X" to make an valid expression,

```
message = filter(lambda x: garbled.remove(x), garbled)
```

Next, I catch the error "'str' object has no attribute 'remove'".
Because type of garbled is string, and there is no attribute that named 'remove' in string type.
To use filter function, first argument must be 'predicate' function (that return True or False), and second argument must be iterable-like. OP's second solution satisfies this condition. second argument is string that is iterable (a list of characters), and first argument is a predicate function that takes one character that is supplied from the second argument string)

Comment: **Thank you for the elegant explanation** remove() cannot be used in string type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. You have a mistake in lambda-condition. You even do not need `string.replace()`.

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
f = lambda x: "" if x in "X" else x
message = filter(f, garbled)
"".join(message)
```